# Voting for 2020 presidential election during out of state move

Tags: united-states, voting, us-state-laws, voter-turnout, vote-by-mail

I imagine that I will be moving states before the 2020 Election Day, and I don’t want to do a mail in ballot, just because I think there’s going to be a lot of BS around that this year. If I’m a tax paying of Iowa, but in September 2020 I move to Washington state, am I still registered to vote in Iowa come November, and should I take a trip back to my old Iowa county to go to the polls?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the person is asking for advice.

Answer (score 2):

In Washington you can vote in person in the 18 day window up to election day. You can also register on election day or before.

https://www.sos.wa.gov/elections/faq_vote_by_mail.aspx

https://www.sos.wa.gov/elections/dates-and-deadlines.aspx

Comment: Of course this year in-person voting may be affected by COVID-19 measures.  For example, the primary election in my state was entirely by mail this year.